# How to separate circles and lines in a binary image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I got a problem and I'm supposed to separate circles and lines in the following image:

[image]

the thing is that I've just made some codes and it's working in a way that only separates them as different objects and the final separated objects are not the same as input ones! I post this question as it might be helpful for someone and if there's anybody that can make a better code to separate objects more clearly and maybe as accurate as the input ones.
I appreciate any comments in advance ...
The code is as follows:

```
clear; close all; clc; warning off

im = imread('input\circle_and_lines.jpg');
level = graythresh(im);
imBin = im2bw(im,level);
figure; imshow(imBin);

%% Separating circles
se1 = strel('disk',6);
imCircles = imopen(imBin,se1);
figure; imshow(imCircles);
[~,numCC] = bwlabel(imCircles,8);
imwrite(imCircles,'output\ex04_circle.png');

%% Separating lines
linDeg0 = imopen(imBin,strel('line',60,0)); figure; imshow(linDeg0);
linDeg10 = imopen(imBin,strel('line',60,10)); figure; imshow(linDeg10);
linDeg20 = imopen(imBin,strel('line',60,20)); figure; imshow(linDeg20);
linDeg75 = imopen(imBin,strel('line',60,75)); linDeg75 = imclose(linDeg75,strel('line',60,75)); figure; imshow(linDeg75);
linDeg95 = imopen(imBin,strel('line',40,95)); linDeg95 = imdilate(linDeg95,strel('disk',1)); figure; imshow(linDeg95);
linDeg135 = imopen(imBin,strel('line',60,135)); linDeg135 = imdilate(linDeg135,strel('disk',1)); figure; imshow(linDeg135);
linDeg170 = imopen(imBin,strel('line',60,170)); figure; imshow(linDeg170);

imLines = linDeg0 | linDeg10 | linDeg20 | linDeg75 | linDeg95 | linDeg135 | linDeg170;
figure; imshow(imLines);
imwrite(imLines,'output\ex04_line.png');
```

The final results are as follows:
[image]
[image]

Comment: you could try using the functions `imfindcircles()` or `houghlines()`. They are both based on the Hough Transform of your input image: http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html   http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html

Comment: Thanks bro.! I could separate circles by imfindcircles() and it's working perfect! but I cannot locate the lines using houghlines() !

Comment: I had the same issues when I tried it for myself. I think the problem might be, that the lines in your image are more rectangles. When you've got an updated version of your code, don't hesitate to post it....

Answer (score 2):

```
% load  image
I = imread('circles_and_lines.jpg');

% Separate the Circles
S1 = strel('disk',6,0);
circles = imopen(I, S1);
figure, imshow(circles);
title('Circles only');

lines = imopen(I,strel('line',60,1));

% Separate the Lines
for c = 1:1:200
    lines = lines + imopen(I,strel('line',60,c));
end
figure, imshow(lines);
title('Lines only');
```

basically a slightly better version of your solution since the for loop scans and separates with more detail the lines

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link below the answer to explain WHY what you propose is "better"? That would make this a much more valuable contribution to the site...